# How to Alias a Page to a Sub-Domain

Tags: wordpress, nginx, dns, alias, cname

I'm running WordPress on a LEMP stack.

I have a landing page at: `https://example.com/landing`

I want to point this subdomain at the above page: `http://landing.example.com`

I don't want to 301/302 redirect the subdomain to the subdirectory.

I want visitors to think they are still on http://landing.example.com.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28243740/create-a-subdomain-alias-that-only-has-access-to-certain-pages) is similar but doesn't solve my particular problem.

I need to know how to rewrite the request with nginx and configure DNS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14491944/nginx-convert-subdomain-to-path-component-without-redirect).

To summarize, you need to proxy the request with nginx:

```
    # abc.example.com
    server {
      listen 80;
      server_name .example.com;
      location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1/abc$request_uri;
        proxy_set_header Host example.com;
      }
    }
```

The just setup an A record pointing at your server's IP.

Answer (score 0):

Link to previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30602324/how-to-detect-an-incoming-request-with-php-script-from-a-cname-subdomain/30630937#30630937) discussing rewrites/redirects/vhosts. You want to rewrite the request and then either land it on the same server or proxy it to a different one.